# Long from List of Characters C#

Tags: c#, .net, arraylist

I have a list of characters `[5, 1, 3]` what is the best way to convert this list to a long like `513` when I do this:

```
long.Parse(charList.ToArray().ToString());
```

I get:

> System.FormatException

Comment: You need to `Join` your array elements - `ToString` will just pass the arrays type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you get a `FormatException` is that the `ToArray().ToString()`'s output is `"System.Char[]"` - which is obviously not a `float` :)

Use `string.Join`:

```
long.Parse(string.Join("",charList))
```

Use `long.TryParse` if there is a risk for non numeric items and use `char.IsNumber` if you want to keep only numeric items:

```
char[] charList = new char[] { '5', '1', '3' };
string.Join("", charList.Where(c => char.IsNumber(c)));
```

Comment: Are you sure this code does what you expect?  Firstly, when I run it (in LinqPad) I get an error that says `items` is not defined.  If I change `items` to `charList`, then I get an output of "TrueTrueTrue".

Answer (score 3):

```
string longList = string.Join("", charList);

long a = 0;
long.TryParse(longList, out a);
```

Answer (score 2):

First way is a direct `Concat` to concatenate a string and then `Parse` it:

```
long result = long.Parse(string.Concat(charList));
```

Aggregation is an alternative

```
long result = charList.Aggregate(0L, (a, c) => a * 10 + c - '0');
```

Comment: the accumulator alternative is by far the most elegant

Comment: `string.Concat` is nice :) forgot about it